# WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi

I'm new in Java EE and in my application I get the following error:

> [2018-12-01 03:23:36,802] Artifact MVSEWebApp:ear exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
>   [2018-12-01 03:23:36,802] Artifact MVSEWebApp:ear exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MVSEWebApp_ear_exploded.ear\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
>       Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name securityBean resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class web.SecurityBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named], Managed Bean [class web.SecurityBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]]"}}

My environment:

- Wildfly 14.0.1
- JSF 2.2
- Primeface 6.1
- IntelliJ Ultimate

My project: [GitHub link](https://github.com/dinci11/MVSEWebApp)

I have read that it could cause that there are two implementationof CDI component, but I don't know how to solve this problem in IntelliJ.

Comment: What about removing the second implementation? Or the first...

Comment: OK, but where can I remove this in IntelliJ?

Comment: No idea... you put them there, a search function might help you

Comment: The exception shows that the bean name `securityBean` is found twice but then it lists the same class (`web.SecurityBean`) twice. This could indicate some mess in your build/deployment where this class gets included twice in the resulting archive (WAR I presume). Try looking in that direction.